# Get the next item in lambda expression

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, lambda

I checked the answered questions but none of them address the issue I have.

I just need to get the **NEXT ITEM** from the table Cars (sql server database) and I have the following query against the EF which kinda ignores the **Skip**:

```
var carid = value;
var car = db.Cars.Where(c => c.CarID == carid).OrderBy(c => c.CarID).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
Response.Write(car.CarID);
```

It **always returns** the very same element as **initial value**. I guess firstordefault is not the way to go.

Thank you

Comment: You always run the same query why do you expect the results to change?

Comment: Yeah but the **value changes each time .. it's a variable. Thx

Comment: Say that var carid = value; is var carid = 123; I need to get the Item with CarID 124. How do i do that? Thank you

Comment: First of all you are filtering the Cars table based on CarID. Then you are ordering based on the CarID, skipping 1 element and taking one element. If this does not end up as null it means you have multiple records with the same ID which is strange...

Comment: @ElizabethDimova thank you for being polite, but no need to add 'Thank you' to every comment. When you filter by using `Where(c => c.CarID == 123)` you already eliminate the car with the `CarID == 124`. The filter expression norrows the result to match the condition. You should change your loginc, may be something like `db.Cars.Where(c => c.CarID > carid).OrderBy(c => c.CarID).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: @ElizabethDimova I am glad that it worked for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Correct code is probably

```
var carid = value;
var car = db.Cars.Where(c => c.CarID > carid).OrderBy(c=> c.CarID).FirstOrDefault();
//needs a null check before using car
Response.Write(car.CarID);
```

(note the > in the where)

However the fact that your previous code did return a value (as opposed to null) means that you have multiple records with the same CarID. This seems wrong.

Also note that the proper code requires autoincrementing IDs in the database.